C++で符号なし3バイト整数のクラスを実装したい
C++で3バイトの符号なし整数を実装したいです。
メモリをケチりたいとかではありません。
挙動としてレジスタ幅が3バイトだったとしたら？というのをシミュレートしたいです。
実装したい演算は以下になります。
=,+,-,&,|,~,^,<<,>>,<,>,<=,>=,==,!=
基本的に符号なし4バイト整数でデータを持って、演算するたびに上位8ビットを0に設定するだけで矛盾なく3バイト符号なし整数として機能するでしょうか？

どこまで正確にシミュレートしたいかによりますが、それだけでは足りないと思います。昔々オーバーフローを制御したくて符号付き整数を模倣したテンプレートクラスを作ったことがありますが、汎整数拡張や他の型との演算が難しかった記憶があります。

長いbit数にする手段/実装があるようなので、それを参考にしてみるとか？ 多倍長整数, C++で多倍長整数クラスを作ってみた(特別編・まとめ), 多倍長整数の実装1（C/C++）, BigIntの実装 in C++

C++ の基本型 (Fundamental type) の具体的な大きさは多くが処理系定義です。
普通のアーキテクチャではハードウェア的に不利なのであえてそういうことをしている処理系ははまずないとは思いますが言語仕様に反しない形で３バイト整数型は存在しうると考えられます。
シミュレートの前提が「３バイトの大きさの整数型が基本型としてもしも存在したら」というものであれば言語仕様を熟読してなるべくその挙動に合致するように実装する必要があります。
異なる型同士で二項演算したときの結果がどういう型になるかなどはルールがややこしいのでそのへんで場合分けを網羅するのが大変な手間だと思います。
(基本型を後付けすることは出来ないのであくまでもなるべく真似をしたクラスということにはなってしまいます。)
対外的な型調整を頑張らないのであれば上位バイトをゼロクリア (ビットフィールドを使ったほうが簡単かもしれません) するだけでもそれなりには使えるでしょうし、シミュレートの想定次第です。

ひとまず、上位バイトのゼロクリアで進めて見ます。ありがとうございます。

unsigned shortやuint16_tのような動作をするような、いわばuint24_tみたいなものを作りたいと言うことですね。であれば、三つの場合に分けを考える必要があります。以下、作成したい型をuint24_tとします。
なお、C++20で規定された、符号付き整数型は2の補数表現であることを前提としてます。ほか、仕様書を細かく確認したわけではないので、間違いがあるかも知れません。(仕様については、暗黙の変換 - cppreference.com等を参考にしました。)
1バイトは8ビットとは限らないのですが、それを想定して数値を一々書くのが面倒になるので、1バイトが8ビットであるとみなしています。ただ9ビットであっても、たぶん、同じような計算になるはずです。
intのビット数が24より大きい場合
現在の多くの環境ではintは32ビットまたは64ビットであり、この場合に該当します。
uint24_tはintよりも小さいため、演算のためにintまたはunsigned intへ整数昇格する必要があります。intは1ビット以上大きいので、uint24_tの全ての整数を表現可能であり、intに昇格することになります。
ということで、+等の算術演算の場合は、intに昇格する、つまり、int型にすれば良いだけです。=で代入するときは、整数変換を行います。符号無し整数の整数変換は、2のn乗(nはその整数型のビット数)で割った余りを求めるもので、符号付きも2の補数表現と既定(C++20)されているため、符号の有り無しに関わらず、25桁以上を0にすれば良いとなります。
実装としては、昇格が不要になるようにint型で持った方が良いでしょう。代入の時にビットクリアすればいいとなります。
intのビット数が24と等しい場合
そのような環境は聞いたことはありませんが、仕様上制限はされていません。
この環境では、uint24_tはunsigned intと同じです。この場合、整数昇格が必要なのかどうかはちょっと自身がありませんが、もし昇格するとしても、intでは収まらないため、unsigned intになります。
ということで、unsigned intへのエイリアスにすれば良いとなります。(uint8_tがunsigned charへのtypedefであったりすることと同じです。)
intのビット数が24より小さい場合
パソコンとかサーバーとかでは滅多に見ることはありませんが、マイコン向けとかではintが16ビットの環境はまだ存在するそうです。
この場合は整数昇格はありません。ですので、unsigned long等と同じような処理でオーバーフローを考える必要があります。
C++の符号無し整数がオーバーフローする場合、2のn乗(nはその整数型のビット数)で割った余りになります(負の場合でも正になる方への余り)。24ビットの符号無し整数であれば224で割った余りになります。また、32ビットの符号無し整数の演算もすべて232で割った余りになるようになっています。
それを踏まえて、次の三つを考えます。

xを232で割った余りを更に224で割った余りは、xを224で割った余りに等しい。
xを2nで割った余りはxと2n-1とのビット論理積と等しい。
xと2n-1とのビット論理積は、n+1以上の桁のビットを全て0にする場合と等しい。

これらが全て正しいのであれば、32ビットの符号無し整数での結果( xを232で割った余り)に対して、上位の25桁目から32桁めのビットを0にする(2n-1とのビット論理積、つまり、224で割った余り)とした値(.xを232で割った余りを更に224で割った余り)こそが、求めるべき値(xを224で割った余り)と等しいとなります。
ここでは、最初の1.だけ証明します。2.と3.が正しいことは自分で調べてください。
xを232で割った商と剰余をqとr(0 ≦ r < 232)とし、さらに、rを224で割った商と剰余をsとt(0 ≦ t < 224)とします。

x = q × 232 + r
x = q × 232 + s × 224 + t
x = q × 28 × 224 +  s × 224 + t
x = (q × 28 + s) × 224 + t

tは0 ≦ t < 224なので、xを224で割った商と余りは(q × 28 + s)とtとなります。tは xを232で割った余りを更に224で割った余りだったので、その値が、tは xを224で割った余りと等しいとなります。
上記は32ビットの整数を使った場合ですが、それ以上でも問題ありません。uint32_tは存在しない可能性がありますが、uint_least32_tはどんな処理系でも(C++11以上に準拠していれば)存在します。ということで、内部実装としてはuint_least32_tをつかって、算術演算を行い、その結果を毎回ビットクリアすれば良いとなります。

ということで

基本的に符号なし4バイト整数でデータを持って、演算するたびに上位8ビットを0に設定するだけで矛盾なく3バイト符号なし整数として機能するでしょうか？

というのはintの大きさによって変わります。例えば、16777215と16777215の乗算(*)は、intが16ビットの環境ではビットを0にした結果の1ですが、intが64ビットの環境では、演算結果はintであり、281474943156225です。なお、intが32ビットの場合は符号付き整数のオーバーフローという未定義の動作になるため、計算結果がどんな値であっても構いませんし、エラーで終了しても良いです(オーバーフローを回避しなかったコードが悪い)。


基本的に符号なし4バイト整数でデータを持って、演算するたびに上位8ビットを0に設定するだけで矛盾なく3バイト符号なし整数として機能するでしょうか？

しますよ

alphaさんと意見が割れてしまいましたね。。。そもそも論として3バイト整数の正確な仕様みたいなものはどこかに存在するものなのでしょうか？何となくこんな感じだろうというのは想像つきますが。

実際に実装してみてはどうでしょう。そうすればできるのかできないのかわかると思いますが
